# Flutter query (where + order by) from firebase firestore returns error

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

My queries from flutter app return error. any ideas why?

```
  Query user = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').where('approvedStatus', isEqualTo: true).orderBy('name');
```

How i show data from query

```
Container(
            child: StreamBuilder(
              stream: user.snapshots(),
              builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Text('Snapshot return error');
                }
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return Text("Loading ..."); // CircularProgressIndicator();
                }
                return Container(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                      return Card(
                        child: ListTile(
                          title: Text(snapshot.data.docs[i]['name'].toString()),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
```

The result i got is snapshot return error

Comment: If you get an error, edit your message to include the exact error message and stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind guys. I found the problem after printing snapshot.error

[cloud_firestore/failed-precondition] The query requires an index.

I just follow the link provided and it solve the problem . Thanks